# i want to search a particular date from table field ,where table field can multiple dates

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is client_details. My table field is dates. dates field contain mutiple dates like

```
03/03/2015,04/13/2015,05/11/2015,06/08/2015,09/04/...
03/18/2015,04/28/2015,05/26/2015,06/23/2015,09/19/...
03/20/2015,04/30/2015,05/28/2015,06/25/2015,09/21/...
03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/...
03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/...
03/06/2015,04/16/2015,05/14/2015,06/11/2015,09/07/....
```

I want to search particular date `'05/06/2015'` from this dates.How can I do it???

Comment: You should split dates by `,` delimiter into rows then you'll be able to search dates ;) Here is an idea how to achieve that: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: What do you have so far? What doesn't work?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `client_details` WHERE STR_TO_DATE( dates, '%m/%d/%Y' ) like STR_TO_DATE( '05/06/2015%', '%m/%d/%Y' ); i wrote this query but it does not showing any result.

Comment: you said dates contain multiple dates, so str_to_date won't work SELECT * FROM `client_details` WHERE dates like '%05/06/2015%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use

```
where dates like '%05/06/2015%'
```

Comment: if it is starting in first, it will display the result.otherwise no result

Comment: Using % on both sides will search anywhere in between also